# Pass Socket_t Pointer to ZeroMQ Send Function

Tags: c++

There is a function that I want to use:

```
static bool s_send(zmq::socket_t & socket, const std::string & string)
```

When the function gets used in the following situation, it throws out runtime error.

```
zmq::socket_t* prt_publisher_socket;
zmq::socket_t publisher_socket(context, ZMQ_REP);

prt_analysis_socket = &publisher_socket;
s_send(*prt_publisher_socket, "testing...");
```

Some thing wrong with the parameter

```
zmq::socket_t & socket
```

How to pass in the **prt_publisher_socket** in the right way?

Comment: `s_send` does not accept an address - it has a reference parameter. Read about references in any good C++ book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo, you assign to `prt_analysis_socket` not `prt_publisher_socket`.

But you don't need a pointer at all, just this should work

```
zmq::socket_t analysis_socket(context, ZMQ_REP);
s_send(analysis_socket, "testing...");
```

Comment: thank you so much. I want to reuse the socket_t pointer since I need to reinitialize them frequently. Is that possible. Or, I have to close the socket and the context in order to recreate them.

Comment: @dongx thats sounds like a new question, and one I don't know the answer to